# How use "cookie-parser" in express right and where are the cookies in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, parsing, cookies, express

first I configure cookie-parser. https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser(secret));
```

Now are the cookies like sid in req.signedCookies, but I don´t need this.
If I connect with socket.io I get the cookies in this way

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    var cookies = socket.handshake.headers.cookie;
    // example: io=AGHGDjbasdqwe7zu23h2AAAA; sid=sn$3kjsd23123asdkjdsdasd123
});
```

Now my problem is, how I get sid extracted from cookies and how I unsign sid?
If I use

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    cookieParser.signedCookie(socket.handshake.headers.cookie, secret);
});
```

I got the same result io=AGHGDjbasdqwe7zu23h2AAAA; sid=sn$3kjsd23123asdkjdsdasd123

Answer (score 1):

You can use `io.use` to add some [authentication middleware](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/), which decodes the sid and adds it to the socket object:

```
io.use(function (socket, next) {

    var data = socket.request;
    if(!data.headers.cookie) 
        return next('No cookie given.', false);

    cookieParser(data, {}, function(parseErr) {

        if(parseErr)  return next('Error parsing cookies.', false);

        var sessionID = (data.secureCookies && data.secureCookies[expressSidKey]) ||
                        (data.signedCookies && data.signedCookies[expressSidKey]) ||
                        (data.cookies && data.cookies[expressSidKey]);

        socket.handshake.sid = sessionID; // Add it to the socket object
    });
});
```

Where `expressSidKey` is something like `express.sid`.

Comment: thanks for comment. 1. this don´t helped me, but the question would sooner or later come from me how to authenticate in socket.io. 2. I solved the problem so that I used two node modules (1. cookie, 2. cookie-parser). With "cookie" I parsed the cookie to JSON, after that I choose the cookie which I want, and then with "cookie parser" I unsigned the cookie. :)